# Hardwiring advice (bit string) into Turing machine

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, busy-beaver

[In paper](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/bb.pdf), page 5, 1st paragraph, it is stated that:

> Notice that an n-state Busy Beaver, if we had it, would serve as an O(n log n)-bit advice string, “unlocking” the answers to the halting problem for all n<sup>O(n)</sup> Turing machines with n states or fewer. Furthermore, this is essentially optimal: if we had an advice string for the n-state halting problem that was much shorter, then by hardwiring that advice into a Turing machine, we could create an n-state machine that determined BB(n) and then ran for longer than BB(n) steps, an obvious contradiction.

By *hardwiring* I understand "revamping" transition table such that it incorporates information from advice.

How do we hardwire, say, n-bit advice into n-state Turing machine? And do I go about proving the optimality i.e. O(n log n)-bit advice string *cannot be hardwired* into n-state TM?